# SqlCommand timeout even though in SQL Studio same query is fast

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have what I thought was a simple query that I execute from my little log-processing application. The aim of this method is to simply get the highest date value out of the log table:

```
private DateTime GetLastEntryDate(string serverName, string siteName)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LogParserDB"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(date) FROM iislogs WHERE host=@Host AND site=@Site", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Host", serverName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Site", siteName);
            var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != DBNull.Value)
            {
                dt = (DateTime)result;
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

There are some indexes on the table, but I'm not sure if that's relevant, because the problem I'm getting is that when I run this code, it throws a timeout after 2 minutes on the `ExecuteScalar` line.

If I copy and paste that query into SSMS with the same parameters, it completes in 00:00:04, or even 00:00:00 (if I've just updated stats).

```
SELECT MAX(date) FROM iislogs WHERE host='servername' AND site='W3SVC1'
```

I have checked for blocking, and I can't see anything like that - that database is *only* being accessed by this one app, and it's not multi-threaded or anything like that.

---

Update:
Interestingly, when I run the exact query as captured by Profiler, it also takes a long time in SSMS:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT MAX(date) FROM iislogs WHERE host=@Host AND site=@Site',N'@Host nvarchar(13),@Site nvarchar(6)',@Host=N'servername',@Site=N'W3SVC1'
```

The actual columns are `varchar(50)` and `varchar(10)` respectively.

Comment: Probably parameter sniffing or the query you execute in SSMS is not actually exactly the same in every respect (including datatypes `nvarchar` vs `varchar`). See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html). You might consider an index on `host,site,date` as well if you don't have one already.

Comment: Also how many rows does the table have?  2 minutes is quite a long time. If you don't have millions of rows maybe the cause lies somewhere else.

Comment: @MartinSmith Interesting on both counts - I think it might be parameter sniffing. If I run the query as captured by Profiler (sp_executesql with parameters) it runs equally slow. I'll have a look. The table is currently 2 million rows or so, but that's just a couple of days' data. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query you execute in SSMS

```
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM   iislogs
WHERE  host = 'servername'
       AND site = 'W3SVC1'
```

Is not the same as the one executed by your application.

```
EXEC sp_executesql
  N'SELECT MAX(date) FROM iislogs WHERE host=@Host AND site=@Site',
  N'@Host nvarchar(13),@Site nvarchar(6)',
  @Host=N'servername',
  @Site=N'W3SVC1'
```

The first one has `varchar` string literals. The second one has `nvarchar` parameters. Your column datatypes are in fact `varchar`.

`nvarchar` has [higher datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than `varchar` so you are forcing an implicit cast of the column. This will render any indexes on the column useless.

Change the parameter datatypes in the application to `varchar`

Comment: Heh, I just spotted the same! I'm moving the data over now and will report back, but this looks like the answer!

Comment: @Cylindric - You can try adding the `N` prefix to the string literals. i.e.  `SELECT MAX(date) FROM iislogs WHERE  host = N'servername' AND site = N'W3SVC1'` to use `nvarchar` string literals and check if the problem now occurs.